# Percentage ratio of areas

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

I don't understand a question from a Math exercise. I did many things asked before, but I found this part very difficult to understand:

> What is the percentage ratio between the combined area of six cylinder bottoms and the area of box bottom in case A?

I just calculated the area of the box (which is a rectangle): 66*396 = 26136. And about the cylinders, we know that h=187 mm and r=33 mm...

Maybe is a problem of my bad English, but I can't answer to the above question. Could you bring me some light?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The cylinders seem to have a circular cross section of radius 33 mm, so the area of the bottom of one is $\pi (33\ \mathrm{mm})^2$.  Six will just fit in a row in a rectangle $66\ \mathrm{mm} \times 396\ \mathrm{mm}$, whose area you have calculated.  So it is $\frac{6 \pi 33^2}{66\times396}$ which should be the same as the ratio between a circle and the circumscribed square (why?).

Comment: @Rahul Narain:  Thanks.